# Scrapy Splash Screenshots?

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape a site whilst taking a screenshot of every page. So far, I have managed to piece together the following code:

```
import json
import base64
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class ExtractSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1
        }
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])

        imgdata = base64.b64decode(png_bytes)
        filename = 'some_image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

It gets onto the site fine (example, stackoverflow) and returns data for png_bytes, but when written to a file - returns a broken image (doesn't load).

Is there a way to fix this, or alternatively find a more efficient solution? I have read that Splash Lua Scripts can do this, but have been unable to find a way to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are decoding from base64 twice:

```
       png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
       imgdata = base64.b64decode(png_bytes)
```

Simply do:

```
    def parse_result(self, response):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'some_image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - very helpful!!

Comment: One more question if you don't mind please is, do you know how to screenshot the entire page? I tried setting `render_all`  to True as part of the args but got this error: `WARNING: Bad request to Splash: {'info': {'argument': 'render_all', 'type': 'bad_argument', 'description': "Pass non-zero 'wait' to render full webpage"}, 'type': 'BadOption', 'description': 'Incorrect HTTP API arguments', 'error': 400}`

Comment: I found the solution - it was to add a delay, allowing the full render to take place! All sorted now, thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ExamOrph where and how I should add a delay? thank you