# A screenshot of a page from a URL without opening it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We need a module that gets a `url` only, and return a screenshot / image of that page ***without*** opening it, so it's being done in the background.

All tools i read about here, are doing so by getting a **specific** `div` element as an input or redirecting to that page.

It also should fit with a `url` that has a *redirect* , so :

```
function getImageOfPage(url) {

  //get html page of this url (dont show it)
  //wait for page to load all photos
  //create screen shot image

  return img;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to get a screenshot of a page from a URL, or do you want to get an image from a URL?

Comment: you could use html-to-canvas with a hidden iframe or something like that, but some websites will not work due to CORS

Comment: thanks. i would like to get screenshot of a page from a url.  html-to-canvas is done on a div element, i need to get a photo of a fully loaded webpage.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172260/scrapy-splash-screenshots#45172646

Comment: If it must be javascript, you'll probably have to use Selenium/PhantomJS or something like that. By the way, all of the scrapers do "open" the site by visiting it. I don't think you can get around that.

Answer (score 1):

there's a solution for this you would need node.js, In this, you need the `webshot` module, `npm i webshot`

here's a sample code

```js
const webshot = require('webshot');

webshot('https://example.com', 
'img_name.png', function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Screenshot taken!")
    }
});
```