# save screen shot of scrapy response

Tags: scrapy

Is there a way to save Scrapy response screenshot of page, I.e

```
scrapy shell "https://google.com" 
view(response)
```

I know I can save the output as HTML and view it later, but is there a way to save the output as image?

I checked this Question [Scrapy Splash Screenshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172260/scrapy-splash-screenshots), (the most relevant one) but I get

```
png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I assume this error is because in Question he uses `Splash Request`,in my case normal `Request`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a screenshot of the webpage or the output in your command line?

The other question you provided seems to be talking about screenshots on the pages being scraped.

The Scrapy documentation has some info on that https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=screenshot#take-screenshot-of-item I'm not sure if splash is required

Comment: it doesn't work,"Could not load image yyy.png" not a PNG file

Comment: Looks like splash is required but the least you can do is answer the question

Comment: well, there is an option I can use but very remote from this, is to simply use headless browser (selenium) and feed it the HTML response and take screenshot there

Answer (score 0):

Splash is the most common approach for this.

See https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-png after you’ve read a bit about Splash in general.